# Using IF in a MySQL query not working - syntax issues

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my query.  $sess is a session variable, which is an account number.  This is where the problem is occurring:  IF(toAcct = $sess, amount, '-'.amount) as amount

If the "to" account = the session variable account number, I want the amount field to be a positive.  If the "to" account <> the session variable account number, I want a - sign before the amount.  I'm just not sure what the syntax should be.

```
SELECT transID, toAcct, fromAcct, 
  IF(toAcct = $sess, amount, '-'.amount) as amount, `description`, 
  `timestamp`, 
  IF(toAcct = $sess, toAcctNewBalance, fromAcctNewBalance) AS balance 
FROM transactions 
WHERE transactions.toAcct = $ACCT or transactions.fromAcct = $ACCT 
ORDER BY transactions.timestamp DESC
```

Thank you all so much!  PHP is not my primary language!

Comment: Is `$sess` a number? what about `$ACCT`?

Comment: If this is MySql then remove the square brackets.

Comment: Use `CASE` instead of `IF` inside `SELECT` clauses.

Comment: @Dai, why? There's no reason not to use `IF` function on a simple condition.

Comment: @danblack Sorry, I was thinking of SQL Server (though in T-SQL there's `IIF( x, y, z )`).

Comment: `case` expressions are standard SQL and portable, and understood by everybody.

Answer (score 2):

This is your code:

```
SELECT transID, toAcct, fromAcct, amount, `description`, `timestamp`,
       IF(toAcct = $sess, [toAcctNewBalance], [fromAcctNewBalance]) AS balance
FROM transactions
WHERE transactions.toAcct = $ACCT or transactions.fromAcct = $ACCT
ORDER BY transactions.timestamp DESC;
```

First, you are using `if()`, which is a FUNCTION, not a STATEMENT.  There is a big difference (see below).  In any case, the problem is the square braces.  Try this:

```
SELECT transID, toAcct, fromAcct, amount, `description`, `timestamp`,
       IF(toAcct = $sess, toAcctNewBalance, fromAcctNewBalance) AS balance
FROM transactions
WHERE $ACCT IN (transactions.toAcct, transactions.fromAcct)
ORDER BY transactions.timestamp DESC;
```

I also simplified the `WHERE` a bit.

As for the terminology.  The [`IF` *statement*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/if.html) is a control flow construct that is only allowed in programming blocks.  That is, in code between `BEGIN`s and `END`s, typically in stored procedures, functions, and triggers.

The `IF()` function is what you are using.  This allows conditional logic in a query.  I prefer using a `CASE` *expression* because that is standard SQL :

```
       (CASE WHEN toAcct = $sess THEN toAcctNewBalance ELSE fromAcctNewBalance
        END) AS balance
```

Answer (score 0):

If `amount` is always positive number, then use this:

```
IF(toAcct = $sess, amount, -amount)
```

if it maybe negative, then:

```
IF(toAcct = $sess, abs(amount), -abs(amount))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got it to work:

```
SELECT   transID, toAcct, fromAcct, 
         IF(toAcct = $sess, amount, -amount) as amount, 
         `description`, timestamp, 
         IF(toAcct = $sess, toAcctNewBalance, fromAcctNewBalance) AS balance 
FROM     transactions 
WHERE    transactions.toAcct = $ACCT OR transactions.fromAcct = $ACCT 
ORDER BY transactions.timestamp DESC;
```